# Call Worklight SQLAdapter and return value

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I used Worklight SQLAdapter to call Oracle procedure to update some values in database and I want return errCode show the update is successful or not?(the errCode is maybe account not exits or balance not enough to transfer...)

Could you show me how to do thats?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can make use of the returned result object after invoking [WL.Server.invokeSQLStoredProcedure](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_method_wl_server_invokesqlstor.html). For that of course, you could add some extra logic to the DB stored procedure to return a different value for every case you want to handle.